# Passing an argument list to Exec?

Tags: ant, gradle

I want to do the following in my Exec task

```
commandLine = [ 'my_executable_path\\' + executable.exe ,
                 argument1,
                 argument2,
                 argument3 ]
```

is it possible to do something like this instead?

```
//...dynamic creation of a List/Array/whatever

    commandLine = [ 'my_executable_path\\' + executable.exe ,
                     myArgumentsList ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm baffled why there are so many questions like this. Is the [DSL reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) too hard to find or make sense of? What can we improve to allow you to answer such questions yourself?

Anyway, the cleanest solution is:

```
task exec(type: Exec) {
    executable = "/path/to/executable"
    args = myArgumentsList
}
```

Comment: a concrete example in the docs, using complex arguments would help. Right now, I'm trying to implement this command `repo forall -cp 'echo \$REPO_PROJECT'` and the docs didn't really give any insight into how to properly split the arguments. I've tried `["forall -cp 'echo \$REPO_PROJECT'"]` and `["forall", "-cp 'echo \$REPO_PROJECT'"]` and `["forall", "-cp", "'echo \$REPO_PROJECT'"]` and `["forall", "-p", "-c", "'echo \$REPO_PROJECT'"]` none of which worked. Knowing which version is 'proper' would make debugging easier.

Comment: Which version is proper depends entirely on the executable and how it expects arguments to be passed.

Comment: This still fails it I try to use curl. Directly on the commandline it fails but through gradle it fails with: [ERROR] [system.err] curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser the dsl reference assumes too much knowledge of gradle+groovy... which keywords are mandatory? what are the defaults? if there is some code that has to be changed, why doesn't it look like in the example? where is the 5 minute tutorial on groovy to understand gradle? practically speaking, gradle is not a (pure) DSL but EDSL, which implies that you need to be able to read and understand groovy. it would be easier to understand if groovy would be excluded just like json excludes javascript. otherwise, for many developers it'll be copy-paste of reference examples and guesswork.